# How to filter views block by content type

Tags: views

1. I added two content types for views slideshows.
2. I added slides to both content types.
3. I created a views slideshow block using one content type.
4. I cloned the above view > Now, I have two views slideshow blocks.

Now, both blocks are linked. Updating one setting updating the other. How can I do the settings so views block1 filtered by content type1 and views block 2 filtered by content type2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter of content:type in one of your display Also,
You can select this block override at the top when you do any specific block related changes. check the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIIx4.png